# UE4 - Cloth collision

Tags: unreal-4, cloth

How is collision working in UE4 Free Asset Paragon-Kallari? It seems like the body of the character and the cape is somehow colliding but I wasnt able to find any physics asset or any setting. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I never worked with specifically Kallari asset, but I worked with Shinbi asset, which is from the same asset pack.

The thing is, Paragon assets were made before [Clothing Tool](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Physics/Cloth/Overview/index.html) built in into the engine, which means they were handled using collision from the APEX clothing data. This APEX clothing method is pretty much outdated by the time 4.16 came out.

Speaking of cloth simulation, you should use the newer [Clothing Tool](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Physics/Cloth/Overview/index.html) method for per vertex cloth simulation. Or if you want for more controlled cloth physics, you can use physics-driven bones on the cloth simulated with [Anim Dynamics](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Animation/NodeReference/SkeletalControls/AnimDynamics/index.html) or [KawaiiPhysics](https://github.com/pafuhana1213/KawaiiPhysics).